# For-Each-Loop through mongoDB collection with javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, collections

I'm working on a little mongoDB project.

I've got 2 collections:

- studentsList
- studentsPresence

I want to check if there is are documents for a student in studentsPresence. If not it should initialize the studentsPresence. Therefor I got this function:

```
// Check if there is a document for the presence for each student
function initializePresenceList () {
    const date = getDate();
    const match = PresenceDB.find({date: date}).fetch();
    if(match[0] == null) {
        const listStudents = ListDB.find();
        for (let student of listStudents) {
            alert('Check');
            PresenceDB.insert({
                _id: student._id,
                beaconID: student.beaconID,
                firstName: student.firstName,
                lastName: student.lastName,
                block1: false,
                block2: false,
                block3: false,
                block4: false,
                date: date
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The `alert('check');` is not executed. So the for part is not being executed.

Comment: I suspect `ListDB.find()` returns undefined or empty. Please try `console.log(listStudents)` before the for-loop to see the value inside the variable.

Comment: Are you using any ORM like mongoose or are you using the native drivers?

Comment: I'm running mongoDB as a service combined with meteor. I'm not sure how to run `console.log(listStudents)`. I do all the testing in a web browser.

I got mongoDB installed in the default way to run as a service and using Compass to interact with it in a GUI.